# How to pass C++/CX structs to pure C++ methods?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

Say I have a legacy pure C++ library that contains a set of functions having C++ structs (native) as their parameters.    This library is gonna be wrapped into a WinRT component that will be used from C# (platform  - Windows Phone).   Obviously, the most simple solution is to repeat all the structures as C++/CX  value structs.
But how to pass these structs to pure C++ functions/methods ? Is it possible ?
If no, what is the solution wrapping the logic in this case?

Answer (score 2):

In general, a [value struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699861.aspx) from C++/CX will require copying of some form in your C++/CX layer, before passing into the native code.  You'll need to marshal the data from the C++/CX form into the native forms you are using.

That being said, the documentation does suggest that you can directly use `memcpy` to copy from a `value struct` to a standard (native) C++ struct, which would be cleaner than mapping the values individually, provided you don't use `String^` or `IBox<T>^`:

> A value class or value struct that contains a Platform::String^ or IBox^ type as a member is not memcpy-able.

Comment: Great that it is possible to use memory copying. But how can one guarantee that those two types of structs has the same size and layout?   Or is it by default ?

Comment: @mr_esp You'd have to design them the same way, using compatible types, if you want to memcpy.  Look at `[StructLayoutAttribute]` and similar for details on the managed side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Read up about P/Invoke and structures. You'll have to replicate the structures and Function declarations in C#, but it generally works rather well. Check out the Docs to `StructLayoutAttribute`, `DllImportAttribute` and `LayoutKind`.

Comment: This is perhaps working on PCs version on WinRT but not on WindowsPhoneRT.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I overlooked that this was for phone. I have no experience in that area.